# Symlinks cannot be created in Powershell 5.1 but can be created by Powershell 7 and Command Prompt

Tags: windows, powershell, symlink

`Windows Developer Mode` is enabled, all of the following are `non admin shells`.
In all of the scenarios detailed below, a file named `target` exists in the current directory.

Via `Powershell 5.1` the following gives an `ERROR`

```
PS C:\Users\user\repos\tmp> Get-Host | Select-Object Version
Version
5.1.19041.610
PS C:\Users\user\repos\tmp> New-Item -Path link -ItemType SymbolicLink -Target target
New-Item : Administrator privilege required for this operation.
At line:1 char:1
+ New-Item -Path link -ItemType SymbolicLink -Target target
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (C:\Users\user\repos\tmp\target:String) [New-Item], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NewItemSymbolicLinkElevationRequired,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemCommand
```

Via `Powershell 7.1` the following works

```
PS C:\Users\user\repos\tmp> Get-Host | Select-Object Version
Version
7.0.2
PS C:\Users\user\repos\tmp> New-Item -Path link -ItemType SymbolicLink -Target target
la---           3/13/2021  1:55 AM              0 link -> target
```

Via both `Powershell 5.1` and `Powershell 7` the following works

```
PS C:\Users\user\repos\tmp> cmd /c mklink link .\target
symbolic link created for link <<===>> .\target
```

Via `Command Prompt` the following works

```
C:\Users\user\repos\tmp>mklink link target
symbolic link created for link <<===>> target
```

Does anyone have an idea why only Powershell 5.1 is giving this error, and is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When Microsoft enabled non-admin symbolic link creation (with developer mode enabled) they did it in a way that all programs not coded to use it can't use it, and updated `mklink` to be able to use it.

Obvious workaround: invoke `mklink` from Powershell via `cmd /c`, which you have already discovered.

Comment: can you elaborate on what "programs coded to use it" are, why is powershell not capable of doing this, did Microsoft forget about it?

Comment: @PhaniRithvij: They added a new flag `SYMBOLIC_LINK_FLAG_ALLOW_UNPRIVILEGED_CREATE` that you have to pass if you don't have admin, and on the first public windows build that enabled it in windows 10 it would fail if you had admin and passed it. I don't know if the second part is still true.